# Perl output array of hashes as table

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

If you have a array of hashes where the key represents the column name and the value is the row content what would be the best way to output this as a table in perl?

Comment: Can you provide some sample output?  (Hint: once you've done that, you'll be able to identify in pseudocode what you need to do with your array of hashes, and then you will be better able to ask a *specific* question about the part you are having difficulty with.)

Comment: I'm using Easy Table for JS. Is there a similar solution for Perl? https://github.com/eldargab/easy-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does each row have the same hash keys?  That's the structure you would get, e.g. from DBI, corresponding to the generally understood properties of tables (i.e. each row has the same set of columns).  Here's a sample of what I have in mind, and I hope it matches what you're thinking:

```
my @AoH = (
    {id => 1, name => 'Dick'},
    {id => 2, name => 'Jane'},
);
```

In such cases you normally know what the columns are.  I'm going to make that assumption.  Here, then, is the code:

```
my @cols = qw(id name);
my @AoH;                 # as above

# print the column headings
print join "\t", @cols;

# print values for each row using a hash slice
for my $row_ref (@AoH) {
    print join "\t", @$row_ref{@cols};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
my @AoH = (
    {a => 1, b => 2},
    {c => 3, d => 4},
);
```

This maps to an N-dimensional table, where N is the number of elements in the array. You can't really visualize it for more than N = 3, unless you collapse the hashes (ie, make it all one big hash.)

If you just mean tabulate a 'reversed' hash, just transpose it:

```
my %a = (a => 1, b => 1);

my %b = map { $a{$_} => $_ } keys %a;

while ( my ($k, $v) = each %b ) {
    printf( "%s %s\n", $k, $v );
}
```

Comment: alternatively: `my %b = reverse %a`.